# How to populate a textbox when an item is selected in a listbox?

Tags: database, vb.net, listbox

I have a listbox that is being populated by a column (Name) from a data set. I want to populate a Textbox on the same form with data from the same dataset but from the column (Desc).  I thought I would use the SelectedIndexChanged event and load the data then filter it out based on the index of the listbox selection.

I 'm not having any success though.  Any one have any suggestion?

I'm using an Access Database: "CCDB.accdb"
and the dataset: "CCDBDataSet"
The Table is: "CrownMods"

Comment: winforms? webforms?

Comment: It's been a while since I've used this, but I think you can have your items contain more data than what is shown. Then you should be able to retrieve that in the Changed event handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need any events.  Simply bind your data to both the `ListBox` and the `TextBox`, e.g.

```
With myListBox
    .DisplayMember = "Name"
    .ValueMember = "ID"
    .DataSource = myDataTable
End With

myTextBox.DataBindings.Add("Text", myDataTable, "Desc")
```

Selecting a Name in the `ListBox` will now automatically populate the `TextBox` with the correspond Desc value.

Comment: Worked Great Thanks!